# retrieving list items from request.POST in django/python

Tags: python, django

In my `request.POST` i am getting a query dictionary , one of the items in this dictionary is a list with multiple items (`pass_id`)
eg.

I want to retrieve each of the values in `pass_id` and store in a new list. Can you suggest the code for this?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist

```
request.POST.getlist('pass_id')
```

Answer (score 6):

Try following django >1.4 and use

```
request.POST.dict()
```

Comment: This doesn't work on lists (need to use `request.POST.getlist`)

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a form, a better approach is:

```
posted = self.fields[field_name].widget.value_from_datadict(
    self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(field_name)
)
```

This will return a list if appropriate for the field, and apply cleaning, prefixing, etc. (I copied this from Django form `form.cleaned_data` method.)