# Django 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, django

Html

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li>java <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="Java"></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>c  <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="C"></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>network <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="Network"></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
  </ul>
```

Python

```
list_categories = request.POST.getlist['categories']
```

This code cause error

> 'instancemethod' object has no attribute `'__getitem__'`.

And I already tried

```
list.categories = request.POST['categories']
```

Comment: Do request.POST.getlist('categories').

Comment: Here's the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430470/retrieving-list-items-from-request-post-in-django-python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
list_categories = request.POST.getlist['categories']
```

for

```
list_categories = request.POST.getlist('categories')
```

`getlist` is a method, so the syntax requires parenthesis.