# Unable to fetch list value - django

Tags: python, django

my posted data looks like this :

**QueryDict: {u'question': [u'how to'], u'submit': [u'submit'], u'tag_name': [u'one', u'two'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'WtOIVwdti7pBaT9LwyYtReS2WEoRpXVJXXLqCDgHaZi14OMmSXkE8g7ccTVTJ48h'], u'ansc': [u'multi'], u'options': [u'3']}**

I'm trying to fetch 'tag_name' data, but each time I do

**request.POST.get('tag_name')**

all i get is

**two**

I'm not able to fetch entire list, even after looping entire request object.

How to fetch this object ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django QueryDict only returns the last value of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565023/django-querydict-only-returns-the-last-value-of-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
request.POST.getlist('tag_name')
```

use this