# Django - pass dict from POST form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

There is a from with various elements

```
<input name='id' value='123'/>
<input name='some_value' value='123'/>
<!-- thing that i want-->
<input name='array[key_1]' value='value_1'/>
<input name='array[key_2]' value='value_2'/>
<input name='array[key_3]' value='value_3'/>
<input name='array[key_4]' value='value_4'/>
</form>
```

If i've been used PHP, array data will be collected in $_POST["array"]
So the questions is, how to collect dict "array" in django views?

Comment: Try printing `request.POST`

Comment: all objects are independent in that way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [retrieving list items from request.POST in django/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430470/retrieving-list-items-from-request-post-in-django-python) Note: You don't need `[key_1]` (and it won't work), etc. you have to name all of the inputs the same as `array`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat That's what I tried to tell, there's no need for accessing key value pairs for further operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's the best way, but it's work.
I've decide to rename params without [] and combine them with dict key with separator "__"

So, here it is

#### template:

```
<input type="text" name="name" 
        value='Yuretz'/>
<input type="text" name="last_name" 
        value='Oguretz'/>

{% for line in print_values %}
<div>
   <b>{{line.name}}</b><br/>
   <input type="text" 
      name="param__{{line.name}}"
      value="{{line.value}}"/>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

#### views.py

```
params_data = {}    
all_post_data = request.POST.dict()
for line in all_post_data:
   if line.startswith('param__'):
       params_key = line.replace('param__','')
       params_data[params_key]=all_post_data[line]
### finally
print(params_data)
```

Hope that will help somebody

Answer (score 0):

You can get all values of the form in the view by giving their `name` attribute in `request.POST` dict so:

```py
def some_view(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
       id=request.POST.get('id')
       some_value=request.POST.get('some_value')
```

Comment: it that way i can't access to keys, only to values.
in fact i need to get dict key=>value pairs

of cource i can get all values and parse them manually, but i think that's not a good way, should be something more simple and beautilfull

Comment: @Yuretz But why do you want to access key value pairs, it's not necessary for saving the form or doing some further operation. Share your form and view and tell what you want to do exactly?

Comment: input form generates from database and when user press submit button i don't know exactly which keys will pass, that's why best way for me to get all variables with name "array"  with key-value pair

Comment: @Yuretz Values passed will be in `request.POST` so `print(request.POST)` and you'll get all values with their name.

Comment: re-read my first reply )

Answer (score 0):

#### Try below code.

#### views.py:

```
def DemotimeView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        data = dict(request.POST)
        del data['csrfmiddlewaretoken']
        print({i:j[0] for i,j in data.items()})
    return render(request, 'index.html',)
```

#### Html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input name='id' value='123'/>
     <input name='some_value' value='123'/>
     <!-- thing that i want-->
     <input name='key_1' value='value_1'/>
     <input name='key_2' value='value_2'/>
     <input name='key_3' value='value_3'/>
     <input name='key_4' value='value_4'/>

     <button type="submit">Add</button>

</form>
```

#### Output:

```
{'id': '123', 'some_value': '123', 'key_1': 'value_1', 'key_2': 'value_2', 'key_3': 'value_3', 'key_4': 'value_4'}
```

Comment: Yes, i've some something like your solution! )